# Проблема с добавлением миграции в asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

создал проект ASP.NET Core MVC, при попытки в командной строке добавить миграцию "PM> Add-Migration InitialCreate" , выдаёт ошибку - "The specified deps.json [C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\MVC Movie\MVC Movie\MVC Movie.deps.json] does not exist".

Среда - Visual Studio Community 2019 (16.9.0) . Ноутбук ASUS X570 UD. Слышал что эта проблема проявляется в ноутбуках HP, из-за системной переменной Platform:MCD, но у себя я такой не обнаружил. Заранее спасибо за ответы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16386 `It's 'Azure development' component which is causing this error (desp.json) , Un-installing that component is fixed this issue`

Comment: ^ там еще в конце есть пара других решений